# Scale Uimage to Large size App be Crashed in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I use VImage to scale Uimage to large size (1920 * 1080), The memory grow up to high and crash app because of memory issue. 
I need use VImage because of it keep some better resolution after scale
thanks!
here my code:

```
func resizeAllImages(){
 for i in 0..<arrNumImages.count {

         let image = arrNumImages[I]
          let  imageXib = image.resizeImageUsingVImage(size: CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)) ?? UIImage()
}
```

// Resize extension of Uiimage

```
 func resizeImageUsingVImage(size:CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let cgImage = self.cgImage!
        var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, colorSpace: nil, bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.first.rawValue), version: 0, decode: nil, renderingIntent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
        var sourceBuffer = vImage_Buffer()
        defer {
            free(sourceBuffer.data)
        }
        var error = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&sourceBuffer, &format, nil, cgImage, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags))
        guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
        // create a destination buffer
        let scale = self.scale
        let destWidth = Int(size.width)
        let destHeight = Int(size.height)
        let bytesPerPixel = self.cgImage!.bitsPerPixel/8
        let destBytesPerRow = destWidth * bytesPerPixel
        let destData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: destHeight * destBytesPerRow)
        defer {
            destData.deallocate()
        }
        var destBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: destData, height: vImagePixelCount(destHeight), width: vImagePixelCount(destWidth), rowBytes: destBytesPerRow)
        // scale the image
        error = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&sourceBuffer, &destBuffer, nil, numericCast(kvImageHighQualityResampling))
        guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
        // create a CGImage from vImage_Buffer
        var destCGImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&destBuffer, &format, nil, nil, numericCast(kvImageNoFlags), &error)?.takeRetainedValue()
        guard error == kvImageNoError else { return nil }
        // create a UIImage
        let resizedImage = destCGImage.flatMap { UIImage(cgImage: $0, scale: 0.0, orientation: self.imageOrientation) }
        destCGImage = nil
        return resizedImage
    }
```

Comment: Don't put all images (`UIImage`) in an array (arrNumImages) so that you can loop through each of them.

Comment: thanks but it's not problem

Comment: change the frame of UIImage according to your size? @Anna

Comment: yes that size of uiiamge Sarah